# Error: Invalid HTML: could not find <table> in xlsx react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import XLSX from 'xlsx';

import CsvViewer from './csv-viewer';

class XlsxViewer extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = this.parse();
}

parse() {
const dataArr = new Uint8Array(this.props.data);
const arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i !== dataArr.length; i += 1) {
  arr.push(String.fromCharCode(dataArr[i]));
}

const workbook = XLSX.read(arr.join(''), { type: 'binary' });
const names = Object.keys(workbook.Sheets);
const sheets = names.map(name => (
  XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(workbook.Sheets[name])
));

return { sheets, names, curSheetIndex: 0 };
  }

renderSheetNames(names) {
const sheets = names.map((name, index) => (
  <input
    key={name}
    type="button"
    value={name}
    onClick={() => {
      this.setState({ curSheetIndex: index });
    }}
  />
));

return (
  <div className="sheet-names">
    {sheets}
  </div>
);
```

}

```
 renderSheetData(sheet) {
 const csvProps = Object.assign({}, this.props, { data: sheet });
 return (
   <CsvViewer {...csvProps} />
 );
  }

  render() {
    const { sheets, names, curSheetIndex } = this.state;
    return (
  <div className="spreadsheet-viewer">
    {this.renderSheetNames(names)}
    {this.renderSheetData(sheets[curSheetIndex || 0])}
  </div>
);
```

}
}

export default XlsxViewer;

i am trying to  load a Xlsx file i am getting error "./src/components/Fileviewer/images/SimpleSpreadsheet.xlsx
Module build failed (from (webpack)-xlsx-loader/index.js):
Error: Invalid HTML: could not find "

the above error  is coming  earlier it was due to the webpack-xslx-loader i have installed and configured  but not the error has been changed